# min-height or full screen fill with jquery mobile dialog box

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to figure out how to enforce a minimum height (for fullscreen effect) on a jquery-mobile dialog box, essentially I'm trying to cover over the backdrop entirely with the dialog box itself.
I'm using a header but no footer if that makes a difference.